# HTTP - Multiple Trailer Headers

Tags: http, http-headers, chunked-encoding, rfc2616

I am trying to implement HTTP in my server, and am unable to find ANY information about how to handle multiple trailer header fields (with chunked encoding).

The standard (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.40) states:
"The Trailer general field value indicates that the given set of header fields is present in the trailer of a message encoded with chunked transfer-coding."

But gives no indication whatsoever of how to specify multiple headers in this the `Trailer` header.

For example, if a request or response had two trailer headers, `Example1` and `Example2`, how would you structure the `Trailer` header?

Like this: `Trailer: Example1 Example2` or `Trailer: Example1,Example2` or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From RFC 2616:

```
14.40 Trailer

       Trailer  = "Trailer" ":" 1#field-name
```

```
2.1 Augmented BNF

#rule
   A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", for defining lists of
   elements. The full form is "<n>#<m>element" indicating at least
   <n> and at most <m> elements, each separated by one or more commas
   (",") and OPTIONAL linear white space (LWS).
```

In other words, you should write:

`Trailer: Example1, Example2`

Note that RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by:

- [**RFC 7230: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)
- [RFC 7231: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)
- [RFC 7232: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Conditional Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232)
- [RFC 7233: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)
- [RFC 7234: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)
- [RFC 7235: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235)

Comment: Thanks - that will help with a lot of future things like that